# Incenter & Barycenter - I was wondering where he got this "$3k$" and this "$2k$" ...

Tags: geometry

In a triangle $ABC$ has $AB = 10cm$ and $AC = 12cm$. Incentive ($I$) and barycenter ($B’$) are in the same parallel to side $BC$. The $BC$ side measurement is equal to:

A friend of mine made this drawing:

[image]
My development went here:

As: $B'G = GB$ and $B'H = HC$

Perimeter $= AH + HG + AG$
Perimeter $= AH + HB '+ B'G + AG$
Perimeter $= AH + HC + GB + AG$
Perimeter $= 12 + 10 = 22$

-I was wondering where he got this "$3k$" and this "$2k$" ...
-I just want this information to continue my development.

Comment: I think it's just saying that the ratio of the two lengths is $2/3$.

Answer (score 2):

You friend must have used the fact that, for the barycenter,  D, F and E are all bisecting points and  $FB’/B’B=FE/CB=1/2$ due to similar triangles. Then, $HB’/CD =2k/3k$ follows.

Since $B’I || BC$, it could be further argued that $HI/CK=HB’/CD  =2/3$, where $K$ is the intercept between the side BC and the line AI (extended to BC).

Then, with the property of the incenter, the following relationship could be established

$ 10+12+BC = 3BC$

to solve for $BC$.